# Want to change image src via button by javascript but code does not work

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am new to Javascript. I just want to change the source of image to different one when user presses one of the 3 buttons. These buttons has different source. I don't know what is wrong with my code, apparently it does not work...

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Change image with button</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Click on the buttons to change image</h3><br/><br/><br/>
    <img id="photo_mine" src="01.bmp"/><br/><br/>
    <button id="one">1</button> 
    <button id="two">2</button> 
    <button id="three">3</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", ch_image("01.bmp"), false);
        document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", ch_image("02.png"), false);
        document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", ch_image("03.jpg"), false);


        function ch_image(source_path) {
            var img_but = document.getElementById("photo_mine");
            img_but.src = source_path;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

PS: Edited all "Document" to "document" and fixed a syntax error.

Now it's weird. The page loads always with the 3rd image (03.jpg) opened, and pressing different buttons do not change the image.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. `Document` does not exist, it should be `document`. You also have a syntax error in the HTML on button with `id="one"` -- there's an extra right parenthesis before the closing tag.

Comment: Changed all "Document" to "document", still not working.
PS: Fixed the syntax error. still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the mistake pointed out in the comments (`Document != document`), your main issue is the fact that you're calling `ch_image` earlier than you think you are. `addEventListener` expects you to pass in a function, but you're actually calling `ch_image` and then passing in the *result*. Your code should actually look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Change image with button</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Click on the buttons to change image</h3><br/><br/><br/>
    <img id="photo_mine" src="01.bmp"/><br/><br/>
    <button id="one">1</button> 
    <button id="two">2</button> 
    <button id="three">3</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", function () {
            ch_image("01.bmp");
        });

        document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", function () {
            ch_image("02.bmp");
        });

        document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", function () {
            ch_image("03.bmp");
        });


        function ch_image(source_path) {
            var img_but = document.getElementById("photo_mine");
            img_but.src = source_path;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

(Additionally, I removed the `false` from each call, as that's the default anyway - you don't need to specify it every time!)

Comment: target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);

listener
    The object that receives a notification (an object that implements the Event interface) when an event of the specified type occurs. This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, or simply a JavaScript function.

IMO i was doing right

Comment: @Miruza: There's an alternate definition if you pass a boolean as the last parameter: `target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture])`. `useCapture` defaults to false, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: I saw the example in the[MDN, 'element.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);' , and i did my code according to that example.

Comment: @Miruza: Yeah, to be fair, some people prefer to be more specific about it :) Neither way is 'right', do whichever feels best for you.

Comment: I was talking about the calling of function, to be exact :), i come from C background.